# UIPageViewController: viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController not called

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios7

I set the dataSource property of the UIPageViewController but its functions never called and the view is empty (black).

If i set at least the first page using the following method, all works well and the dataSource methods are called:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

It seems weird to me that i have to set any controllers manually. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Did you set yourself as the pageViewController's delegate and data source? i.e. yourInstanceOfPageViewController.delegate = self; yourInstanceOfPageViewController.dataSource = self;

Answer (score 1):

You should provide initial viewController. Use data source to provide additional view controllers to which users navigate.

Comment: So there is no real way to create a generic UIPageViewController with my own logic? It would be hard to do so if i have to set initial view and not only a dataSource

Comment: No, Can you give detail of what you are going to achieve ?.

Comment: I am trying to create a generic page view controller that displays pages on full screen.